# Uniform random positive decimal number in bash

Tags: bash, shell, random

I would like to make a random ICMP traffic using ping. I need to make a random decimal number between 0.5 to 1 for time parameter in my code. Could you please show me how to make uniform random decimal number? My code just can make a integer number. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i = 0; i <=100; i++))
do
#need to have random number between 0.5 to 1 for time
time=$(($RANDOM%5+1))
num=$(($RANDOM%5+1)) 

ping -c $num -i $time 10.0.0.2 

done
```

Comment: your command line options are mixed up. `-c` specifies the count, not the interval, which is what `-i` does. Anyway, what have you tried so far? Why not simply divide by a floating point number and be done?

Comment: `echo "0.$(( ($RANDOM%500) + 500))"`

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Sorry, it was a mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Is it a uniform random number?

Comment: @Queen do you want a mathematically accurate answer to that question or would a "for all your purposes, yes, whatabout you just try?" suffice?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I have tried it but it shows me "ping: bad timing interval"! Any way, thanks for your answer, :))

Comment: @Queen that's not a problem of the bash script. Read the `ping` manpage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't actually *do* decimal number, only integers, but you can fake decimals by generating integers and putting a decimal point at the start.

Try this:

```
echo "0.$(( ($RANDOM%500) + 500))"
```

As regards it being uniform, you can generate 10,000 samples like this:

```
for ((i=1;i<10000;i++)) ; do echo "0.$(( ($RANDOM%500) + 500))" ; done > data
```

And then plot the frequency distribution with **gnuplot** like this:

```
gnuplot --persist <<EOF

# Make some suitable labels.
set title "Number Distribution"
set xlabel "Value"
set ylabel "Count"

set style histogram clustered gap 1
set style fill solid border -1

binwidth=0.01
set boxwidth binwidth
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) + binwidth/2.0

plot 'data' using (bin(\$1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes
EOF
```

[image]